# "plugin 'bridge' not found" when creating Docker network with docker compose driver bridge

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm encountering an error while trying to create a Docker network. The error message I receive is:
[image]

This error seems to be related to the Docker networking configuration. I'm using Docker on Ubuntu 20 I think, and I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Can someone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how I can fix it?

**Additional Details**:

Docker version: Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
Operating system: 20.04

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db :
    build : ./database/
    ports :
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./database/create_fixtures.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_fixtures.sql
    networks:
        network:
              ipv4_address : 172.20.0.3
      
  pgadmin:
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        environment:
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=root
        ports:
            - "5050:80"
        networks:
            network:
              ipv4_address : 172.20.0.2

  app :
    build: ./app/
    networks:
        network:
    depends_on : 
      - db
networks:
  network:
    ipam:
      driver: bridge
      config:
        - subnet : "172.20.0.0/16"
          gateway: "172.20.0.1"
```

I have already tried the following steps:

- **Restarting Docker**: I restarted the Docker service and also rebooted
  my computer, but the issue persists.
- **Checking Docker Networking Plugins:**

[image]

- **Verifying Docker Configuration**: I checked the
  Docker daemon configuration file (/etc/docker/daemon.json on Linux) and It doesn't exist i never created one

  present. Despite these attempts, the problem remains. I would
  appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this issue. Thank
  you in advance for your help!

Despite these attempts, the problem remains. I would appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by simply removing driver: bridge from the docker compose file

Answer (score 2):

Delete *all* of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file.

You've shown a lot of manual setup here that Docker does automatically.  If you have no `networks:` declared, Compose creates a network named `default` and attaches all of the containers to it.  Docker then automatically assigns IP addresses to containers, and provides a DNS system that can resolve the container names to those IP addresses.

This means you almost never need to worry about the container-internal IP addresses at all.  They're not reachable from outside Docker (except on one very specific Docker host setup), and within Docker you can use the Compose service names as host names.  For example, you could set an environment variable `PGHOST=db` on the `app` container, and that will resolve to the database container.

In your question and other answer you hint at problems manually specifying the network `driver:`.  In non-Swarm mode, the `bridge` driver should be the default mode and you don't need to specify that explicitly.

[Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation has more details about what gets set up automatically, and how to override the `default` network configuration if you absolutely need to.